# count number of files in directory with a certain name

Tags: ls, wc

I found this code here https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x700.html which nicely gives me the number of files in my directory.

```
ls -1 | wc -l
```

but I only want to know how many of those files' names start with 2009 (for example `20091210_005037.nc`).

I tried `ls -1 | wc -l 2009*` but that slowly lists all the files and does not seem to give me a number.

Comment: `ls` is doing the listing, so the filenames should be given to `ls`.

Comment: You want to list all 2009-files and then count the output lines: `ls 2009* | wc -l`. Jsut remember the names of the command ls = list , wc = word count (-l = lines). Beware of dangers with `ls` for odd file namings, though. Using `find` might be saver.

Comment: And the option `-1` is not neccessary. For a piped output, `-1` is default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
set -- 2009*
echo "$#"
```

This sets the list of positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, ..., etc.) to the names matching `2009*`.  The length of this list is `$#`.

---

The issue with `ls -1 | wc -l 2009*` is that you execute `wc -l` directly on the files matching `2009*`, counting the number of lines in each.  Meanwhile, `ls -1` is trying to write to the standard input of `wc`, which `wc` is not reading from since it was given an explicit list of files to work on.

You may have wanted to use `ls -d 2009* | wc -l`.  This would have listed all the names that match `2009*` (using `ls` with `-d` to not list the contents of directories), and would count the number of lines in the output.  Note that `-1` is not needed if you pipe the result of `ls` somewhere (unless `ls` is an alias or shell function that forces column output).

Note also that this would give you the *wrong* count if any filename contains a newline:

```
$ touch '2009
> was
> a
> good
> year'
$ ls
2009?was?a?good?year
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 May 28 11:09 2009?was?a?good?year
$ ls -1
2009?was?a?good?year
$ ls | wc -l
       5
$ ls -1 | wc -l
       5
```

However:

```
$ set -- 2009*
$ echo "$#"
1
```

(using `set` and outputting `$#` additionally does not use any external commands in most shells)

---

Using `find` to count recursively:

```
find . -type f -name '2009*' -exec echo . \; | wc -l
```

Here, we output a dot for each found pathname in or under the current directory, and then we count the number of lines that this produces.  We don't count the filename strings themselves, and instead do it this way to avoid counting too many lines if a filename contains newlines.

With `find` we're able to more closely control the *type* of file that we count.  Above, we explicitly test for *regular files* with `-type f` (i.e. not directories and other types of files).  The `*` pattern in the shell does not distinguish between directories and files, but the `zsh` shell can use `*(.)` to modify the behaviour of the pattern to only match regular files (the `zsh` user would probably use `2009*(.)` instead of `2009*` in the non-`find` variations above and below).

Using `**` in (with `shopt -s globstar` in `bash`, or `set -o extended-glob` in `yash`, or in any other shell that may support it), to count recursively:

```
set -- **/2009*
echo "$#"
```

The pattern `**` matches almost like `*`, but also matches across `/` in pathnames.

Comment: GNU `find` also supports the `-printf` action, which saves you a fork and exec, and may be more efficient than `-exec echo .`.

Comment: Or even without GNU, `-exec printf '.\n' +` will use _few_ fork/exec.

Answer (score 3):

Tried with below command and it worked fine  and got the result

```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "2009*" | awk '{print NR}'| sed -n '$p'
```

Note: If you want to under subdirectory also Kindly remove maxdepth option

Comment: Re: the recent edit, see [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521469/117549) where this would miscount files with newlines in their name.

Comment: Or just `find ... | awk 'END {print NR}'` (modulo the newline issue)

Comment: This returns a) N if you have 1 or more matches or b) NULL if there's no match. Aspect b) was important to my application. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the people in the comments, this is the answer to my question:

```
ls 2009* | wc -l
```

or using find

```
find 2009* | wc -l
```

Comment: The `find` command is a bit nonsensical. If you wanted to do a recursive `find`, you would not use `2009*` as the search path.

Comment: See [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521469/117549) where this would miscount files with newlines in their name.

Answer (score 0):

To count number of files starting with a particular filename using awk.

```
root@ubuntu$ find . -name "2009*" | awk 'BEGIN{total=0}; {total=total+1} END {print "total files starting with 2009 is " ,total}'
total files starting with 2009 is  4
```

Comment: The `BEGIN` block is not needed. An uninitialised variable in `awk` will have the value zero when used in an arithmetic context.

Comment: And awk's builtin NR already gives the record number, as in Praveen's answer